# IAM permissions to save file to s3 by serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy a lambda which uploads files to s3, for permissions i don't want to attach role instead manually assign permissions to function myself.

these are the additional permissions statements i have added in my `serverless.yml`

```
region: ap-south-1
#role: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/cm-jatin-mehrotra-lambda
provider:
    iam:
     role:
      statements:
       - Effect: "Allow"
         Action:
          - "s3:ListBucket"
         Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::name-of-bucket/*"
       -  Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
           - "s3:PutObject"
          Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::name-of-bucket/*"
```

Every time I try to test run my lambda I see this error

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
```

Comment: If you check in AWS Lambda console, can you verify that its execution role has correct permissions?

Comment: execution role? means the role needed by lambda to do a task right? let me check

Comment: Yes, does it have to needed S3 permissions?

Comment: Why do you have `provider` indented? Isn't it a root-level object?

Comment: @marcin my doubt is that when i mentioned permissions in yml file, apparently the role should inherit these permissions however what i observed that there was a new role created by the serverless framework in which i had to manually add the same permissions and then everything works.
so why did that role didn;t inherit permissions from the yml file?

Comment: @jarmod that was a typing mistake

Comment: FYI the ListBucket resource is incorrect. This action applies to a bucket, not to objects.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you defining two policy statements?

```
- "s3:PutObject"
```

Should be immediately under

```
- "s3:ListBucket"
```

And you should have just 1 policy statement for the bucket.